# If/else statement in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm working on a wordpress website where I'm trying to create a table with real-time cryptocurrency prices and price changes. I am using the coinmarketcap v2 api (https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) to fetch the real time values. Im using a Wordpress plugin (shortcoder) that I can use to shortcode pieces of script.

What I want to do is to style the 24h change percentage value based on whether its value is negative or positive. I have tried both ways of styling seperately and they work.

However, what I cant get to work is the if/else statement in the jQuery to determine whether the 24h change percentage is negative. The jquery script I've tried to create is:

```
(function($){
$.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/', function( data ){
    if(data['data']['quotes']['USD']['percent_change_24h']>=0){
        $('#btc_24h').html('<span style="color:green;"> '+data['data']['quotes']['USD']['percent_change_24h']+'%</span>');    
    }else{
        $('#btc_24h').html('<span style="color:red;"> '+data['data']['quotes']['USD']['percent_change_24h']+'%</span>');
});
```

Unfortunately I am not that much of a jQuery hero and I've been trying to figure the problem out all morning. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?...

When I delete the if/else statement and just try both types of styling seperately they both work fine...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Which branch is executed? Is there any error in the console? What does `data['data']['quotes']['USD']['percent_change_24']` contain exactly? Have you tried to print it to the console?

Comment: Else loop is not closed. Not sure if it was missed while copy-pasting it in stackoverflow. Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrYLGE) for the same

Comment: Try to force it to `int` : `(int) data['data']['quotes']['USD']['percent_change_24h']`

Answer (score 0):

Despite checking it over and over 4 times I still must have missed the closing of the else loop. So silly...

Thanks @Madhan M!